# Is it possible to loop when compiling with protobuf, converting .proto files to .py files?

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-recognition

I was setting up an environment for an object recognition project using TensorFlow. When it came to compiling some .proto files I hit a wall. It took the efforts of find the path to the files / then find the path to the protobuf app / then go ahead and command `-- python_out=.` for every single proto file!!

**What I'm doing / trying to do:**
Following this (https://www.edureka.co/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-tutorial/#object) tutorial sort of thing on edureka I managed to:

- keep “models” and “protobuf” under one folder “Tensorflow“
- go inside the Tensorflow folder and then inside research folder and run protobuf from there using this command:

  `"path_of_protobuf's bin"./bin/protoc object_detection/protos/`

**The Commands**

```
C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop\TensorFlow\protoc-3.5.1-win32\bin\protoc object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto --python_out=.
C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop\TensorFlow\protoc-3.5.1-win32\bin\protoc object_detection/protos/argmax_matcher.proto --python_out=.
C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop\TensorFlow\protoc-3.5.1-win32\bin\protoc object_detection/protos/bipartite_matcher.proto --python_out=.
```

....and so on until you finish all items in the protos folder

So what this did was basically allow me to compile as a .py file under every proto file. I do happen to have a lot more to go ahead and command, so for productivity - How can I loop this to do just the exact same task over and over through the proto files that need to be compiled?

Comment: Normally this type of task would be automated with a script. Bash is quite common, I see you're on windows so you could use python to execute the shell commands or powershell alternatively. The script would search for `.proto` files under the project root and then run `protoc </path/to/proto/> --python-out=.` for each file it discovers

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand something. Why not simply `C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop\TensorFlow\protoc-3.5.1-win32\bin\protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`? (Note the asterisk instead of file name)

Comment: Just because there were around 40 files to comment that for - [time is money.](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LVUvf8cISEE/hqdefault.jpg) I looked at windows script host uses though; I fixed the issue now - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this following these steps:

1. Navigate to the `Tensorflow\models\research` folder in command line (Path may vary in your case)
2. Enter this command `for %i in (object_detection\protos\*.proto) do protoc %i --python_out=.`

It'll create `.py` file for each `.proto` file in the `Tensorflow\models\research` folder as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1zA7.png)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, once I'm in the research directory, I tried `protoc object_detection/protos`. 
Then, this error appeared:

```
Command 'protoc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install protobuf           # version 3.6.0, or
sudo apt  install protobuf-compiler

See 'snap info protobuf' for additional versions.`
```

So, I install the necessary package by typing: `sudo apt install protobuf-compiler`

Followed by: `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --py`

Finally, you can check in the "object_detection" folder and you can see that a .py file has been generated for each file in that folder.